# Problem with making CSS Sprite in my project?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a problem with making CSS Sprite. This is the first time I'm using sprite so I am not pro with it.

This is HTML code:

```
<div class="dfeature-box">
<div class="icon"><img class="multi" src="images/sprite.jpg"></div>
<div class="title">Title</div>
<div class="details">description.</div>
</div>
```

And this is CSS code:

```
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 30px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 272px;
}

.dfeature-box .icon {
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 106px;
height: 106px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 16px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 35px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.dfeature-box .icon .multi{
background-position:126px 9px; 
height:47px; 
width: 64px;
```

And this is the image I want to use (3 icons in one image) - in my codes, I've used the last image (two people)

[image]

And this is the result (as you see all 3 images stuck together):

[image]

I have an important question too:
How can I use the image in CSS instead of using it in HTML (class=icon)? as you see "img" is used within "class=icon".

**==>> First update:**

Please check these new codes based on your suggestion:
Here is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtueN.jpg)

CSS:

```
.sprite-bg{
background: url("images/sprite.jpg");
}

.bg-1{
width:62px;
height:62px;
background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dfeature-box">
<div class="icon"><div class="sprite-bg bg-1"></div></div>
<div class="title">Title</div>
<div class="details">Description</div>
</div>
```

Look at this HTML code:
Are you sure about red marked part? What should I put there?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PoSy.jpg)

Also, please take a look at my codes in my first post. I want to use sprite into my codes.

**==>> Second update:**

```css
.dfeature-box {
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 30px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 272px;
}

.dfeature-box .icon {
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 106px;
height: 106px;

background-color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 16px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 35px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
-webkit-transform-origin: center center;
-moz-transform-origin: center center;
-ms-transform-origin: center center;
transform-origin: center center;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(31, 27, 90, 0.08);
box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(31, 27, 90, 0.08);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sprite-bg{

background: url("https://i.imgur.com/VO1dBBA.jpg");

}
.bg-1{
    width:62px;
    height:62px;
    background-position: 0px 61px;
}
.bg-2{
    width: 64px;
    height: 62px;
    background-position: 62px 61px;
}
.bg-3{
    width: 64px;
    height: 62px;
    background-position: 127px;
}

.dfeature-box .icon i {
    font-size: 50px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #45b35e, #6ad56a);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #45b35e, #6ad56a);
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hustbee</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
 <body>
   <div class="dfeature-box">
                    <div class="icon"><div class="sprite-bg bg-1"></div></div>
                    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
                    <div class="details">long description.</div>
                </div>


                <div class="dfeature-box">
                    <div class="icon"><div class="sprite-bg bg-2"></div></div>
                    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
                    <div class="details">long description.</div>
                </div>

                <div class="dfeature-box">
                    <div class="icon"><div class="sprite-bg bg-3"></div></div>
                    <div class="title">TITLE</div>
                    <div class="details">long description.</div>
                </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check below answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Below Example:

There are several things you need to check on :

1. Sprite image always called on `backgound:url(path to image)`
2. create 3 classes for icons.
3. call the different positions of image.

```css
.sprite-bg{
 
  background: url(https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/373_sprites/angry_birds.png);

}
.bg-1{
 width:110px;
  height:110px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.bg-2{
 width: 58px;
    height: 60px;
    background-position: 194px 89px;
    //border: 2px solid red;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite-bg bg-1"></div>
<div class="sprite-bg bg-2"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, please have a look at my update, I'm still having problem

Comment: Hello, Can you please share a code snippet or  codepen?

Comment: Hi @Amarjit Singh . Done. I just found strange stuff! If I run the code in the stylesheet file (style.css), it does not work, while it works as an inline code!

Answer (score 0):

You must split your image into 3 separate files. if you want to use them individually since you cannot split images using html/css

> I have an important question too: How can I use the image in CSS instead of using it in HTML (class=icon)? as you see "img" is used within "class=icon".

Yes, you can add the `background` property to your class and load a image using `url("...")`

```css
background: url("img/sprite.jpg");
```